Infinite series and sum of two squares
Consider the following infinite sequence $a(n)$ generated by
$$\sum_{n\geq0} a(n)q^n
=\frac{\sum_{k\geq0}F(2k+1)q^{\binom{k+1}2}}{\sum_{k\geq0} q^{\binom{k+1}2}}$$
where the $F(2k+1)$ are the odd Fibonacci numbers (understood as $F_1=F_2=1$).
The following observation I have found and it seems rather amusing.

QUESTION. Is this true? $a(n)\not\equiv0\pmod 5$ iff $n$ is a sum of two squares.


Not quite; $a(625) \equiv 0 \bmod 5$.  But it's very close,
probably for good reason having to do with modular forms mod 5.

Indeed the numerator is soon seen to be congruent mod 5 to the
familiar modular form
$q^{-1/8} \eta^3 = 1 - 3q + 5q^3 - 7q^6 + 9q^{10} - + \cdots$,
so the quotient is congruent to $\theta(-q)^2$ where
$\theta(q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}$.
This means $a(n)$ is congruent to $(-1)^n$ times
the number of representations $n = a^2 + b^2$ ---
and this count is first divisible by 5 (without being zero) for $n = 5^4$.

Thank you, indeed. Here are the next few numbers failing ${25^2, 50^2, 75^2, 100^2, 150^2, 169^2, 175^2}$. Request: if you post your reply in the answer box, I vote for you. We don't want this to be buried in the comments.

Done.  There are also exceptional $n$ that are not square,
starting with $5^4 c$ for $c = 2, 8, 13$.

Expanding on my comments: $a(n)$ is congruent mod 5 to the number of
two-square representations $n = r^2 + s^2$
(allowing each of the integers $r,s$ to be positive, negative, or zero).
Thus if $n$ has no such representation then indeed $a(n) \equiv 0 \bmod 5$,
while if $n$ is a sum of two squares then usually $a(n)$ is nonzero mod 5,
but there are exceptions such as $n = 625 = 5^4$.  In general
$n$ is exceptional iff $p^{5e-1} \| n$ for some prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$
and positive integer $e$.
We explain this as follows.  It is well-known that the Fibonacci numbers
are periodic mod 5 with period 20.  Thus $\{F_{2k+1} \bmod 5\}$ has period 10.
We find that the period is $1,2,0,3,4,4,3,0,2,1$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots,9$,
which is also congruent mod 5 to the nonzero coefficients
$1,-3,5,-7,9,-11,\ldots$ of the weight-3/2 modular form
$$
\eta(q)^3 = q^{1/8} (1 - 3 q + 5 q^3 - 7 q^6 + 9 q^{10} - 11 q^{15} + - \cdots).
$$
Multiplying the denominator $\sum_{k\geq 0} q^{k+1 \choose 2}$
by the same factor of $q^{1/8}$ yields a modular form of weight 1/2,
namely the shifted theta function
$$
\frac{\eta(q^2)^2}{\eta(q)}  = \frac12 \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty q^{(2k+1)^2/8}
 = q^{1/8} (1 + q + q^3 + q^6 + q^{10} + q^{15} + \cdots).
$$
Thus the quotient is congruent mod 5 to $\eta(q)^4 / \eta(q^2)^2$,
which is the square of the weight-1/2 form
$$
\frac{\eta(q)^2}{\eta(q^2)} = \sum_{r=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^r q^{r^2}
 = 1 - 2q + 2q^4 - 2q^9 + 2q^{16} - + \cdots.
$$
This proves the claimed congruence
$a(n) \equiv (-1)^n \# \{ (r,s) \in {\bf Z} : n = r^2 + s^2 \} \bmod 5$.
The criterion for this to be $0 \bmod 5$ when $n$ is a sum of two squares
then follows from the formula $4 \prod_{p \equiv 1 \bmod 4} \, (1 + v_p(n))$
for the number of two-square representations of such $n$.
